# Change background color and active div color

Tags: javascript, jquery

im building a navigation and i want to add some functions.

On click on a div the navigation background color fades then the active button fades the color but when i click on another menu button the color from the previous button is actually there ... i want that only the acutally button fades the color and the background from the navigation and the previous removes the color

```
$('.re').click(function() {
    $('.re').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$("#home0").click(function() {
    $("#navigation").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"grey"}, 800);
    $(".active").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"green"}, 800);

});

$("#home1").click(function() {
    $("#navigation").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"black"}, 800);
    $(".active").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"green"}, 800);
});

$("#home2").click(function() {
    $("#navigation").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"grey"}, 800);
    $(".active").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"green"}, 800);
});
```

This is my Code but it doesn't work :/

**EDIT:** Here is my Fiddle: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tqYrT/1/)

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: Please also include the relevant HTML markup or create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tqYrT/

Comment: In the code posted here, you are targeting an id `#home0` rather than a class `.home0`. Refer to your fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tqYrT/1/ satisfied?

Comment: Your original fiddle was fine. I was referring to the code you posted here. It doesn't seem to appear in your fiddle.

Comment: please click more than one div and you will see the color of the previous is still there but ONLY the actually clicked div must be green ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are changing the color with javascript instead of CSS you need to remove the `style` attribute together with the `active` class..

```
$('.re').removeClass('active').removeAttr('style');
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/tqYrT/3/

---

But you should really handle this with CSS and transitions.. (see [Using CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions))

Comment: Yeah! Really Nice! Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 for a solution that applies directly to the OP's existing code and for referencing an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) to animate changes to CSS. Here's an example:

### HTML:

Here, I am storing the desired nav background color as a custom data attribute (data-navbg):

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="box" data-navbg="gray"></div>
    <div class="box" data-navbg="black"></div>
    <div class="box" data-navbg="gray"></div>
    <div class="box" data-navbg="black"></div>
    <div class="box" data-navbg="gray"></div>
</div>
```

### JQUERY:

Here, when clicking a box, all boxes are set to not active, the clicked box is set to active, and the nav background is set to the desired color specified by the `navbg` attribute of the clicked box.

```
$('.box').click(function () {
    var navbg = $(this).data('navbg');
    $('.box').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('div#navigation').css('backgroundColor', navbg);
});
```

### CSS:

Here, the first definition applies CSS transitions to both the nav and the boxes:

```
#navigation, .box {
    -moz-transition:0.25s;
    -webkit-transition:0.25s;
    -o-transition:0.25s;
    transition:0.25s;
}

#navigation {
    background-color: black;
    height:60px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #787878;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box.active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[Working Example (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/tqYrT/5/)

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much for your work and your explanation! you're crazy! Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this too if you can. Nobody seems to can help me for weeks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175044/multiple-actions-div-moves-up